# selective search & replace of text string in many HTML-Docs

Tags: html, query-string, replace

I've got many html-docs that need selective replacement of the `<br />` tag in two specific areas in each document (400+).
I wonder how to achieve this goal and need assistance.

In each HTML-document the `<br />`-tag needs to be replaced only inside the html-tag:
`<span property="dc:description" content="xyz1,<br /> xyz2,<br /> xyz3"/>`
and also all occurences of `<br />`inside the `alt="`-tag, like in the html-tag
`<img src="xyz.jpg" alt="uvw1,<br />uvw2" />`)

In all other areas of the HTML-Docs the `<br />`-tag must remain unchanged.

...I gave this some more thought and think the problem described above may be resolved with the aid of a script or a function equipped with start- and stop-signals. This way the script knows at which positions to start looking for the `<br />`-tag and replace it with a given text-string AND also knows where to stop. Then move on to the next instance in documents that are open in an editor or residing in a given folder.

I am afraid that I am not capable to write such a script myself.
Hope someone can provide feedback on how to best accomplish this,
thanks.

OS: Win7-64, Editor: Notepad++

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Providing that your HTML files aren't really big, I don't think you need a script for this.

You could just:

1. Join the files together.
2. Use a regex replace in Notepad++. For this you need to replace `<span([^/]*)<br />(.*)"/>` with `<span\1NEWTAG\2"/>` where `NEWTAG` is whatever you want to replace the `<br />` with. Note that this will only replace the first `<br />` it finds each time, so you will need to do this a few times until it finds no more. Therefore if you're replacing with text that contains `<br />` itself (which I doubt by the sounds of it), you'll need to modify this a little.
3. Split the file back up into the originals.

Personally I'd just write a Python script, as it's pretty ace at string manipulation. But I don't know if this is within your scope.

Comment: thanks for reply  
1. joining the files together is not feasible

Comment: 2. the tags remain, only BR needs to be replaced within the tags.

Is that what your code suggests?  
What do I need to insert in the search-field, what to insert into the replace field? Sorry, I don't quite get it.

Comment: replace with NEWTAG works in the first run, but does not work in the second run. What modification is needed?

Comment: Ok, it works fine with Notepad++ by selecting the tab 'find in files' and then 'replace in files'. Had to apply the reach-replace term several times till 0 occurences were found. Thanks, @melkamo, this is solved.

Comment: @snahl: Glad it worked. I'd never noticed the "Replace in files" feature before - Notepad++ continues to surprise.